# How to download file through javascript in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a link /api/ticket/1/download to my server and if I copy paste it into the browser, it will start a download of my file with it's filename extension and everything set up already.

How can I do it in javascript? With `thymeleaf` i was just using `<a href="myLink">` and it worked like if I paste it in the browser. But due to `react-router` `a href` just goes to another page.
But if I use `await fetch` like this:

```
let url1 = '/api/ticket/' + fileId + '/download';
        const response = await fetch(url1);
        const blob = response.blob();
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', `file.jpg`);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
```

i can transfer response into blob, but then i miss the files name and extension.

Comment: Could you please give an example link ?

Comment: `link.setAttribute('download', "filename.jpg");` here is the name of the file.

Comment: it is name that i hardcoded, not the name of the file stored on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this that i found is: send file name and extension in a response header and than parse them manualy.
like:
in spring:

```
myControllerMethod( HttpServletResponse response){
...
 response.setContentType(att.getType());
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + myFileName + "\"");
}
```

in react:

```
const headers = response.headers;
const file = headers.get("Content-Disposition");
```

and then parse manully this 'file' to get filenamel;

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way, it may help you :

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/employees/download')
            .then(response => {
                response.blob().then(blob => {
                    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    let a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'employees.json';
                    a.click();
                });
```

For more reference you can go through [This link](https://www.roytuts.com/download-file-from-server-using-react/)

Comment: What is the difference between your soluttion and mine? The problem is the same. File ALREADY have name and extension when it is sent from the server. I don't want to insert my own new. I want to get the name and extension like it browser does when i paste link directly into it.